# initState is not being called from a model class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I'm having trouble with the initState method of a widget I would like to use.

For some context, I'm trying to make a movie viewing app for a project, and I have to use data from tmdb. This is where things get a little funky as the design of the app should show rows of two movie posters. To do this, I made a method that would retrieve the necessary data and use them to create widgets and add them to a list. But I noticed that the initState method of those widgets is not working, I need this to work as I needed to pass the poster link. My theory is that, since it's being called from a method, it doesn't actually initialize the state; hence no values are actually being passed.

This is the code of the method

```
Future<List<Widget>> getSuggestedMovies() async{
    Network network = Network('$tmdUrl/trending/all/day?api_key=$apiKey');
    var suggestedMovies = await network.getData();
    List result = suggestedMovies['results'];
    int i = 1;
    List<Widget> column = [];
    List<Widget> row = [];


    result.forEach((dynamic movie) {
      Poster poster = Poster(posterLocation: 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500'+movie['poster_path']);
      row.add(poster);

      if((i % 2) == 0){
        SuggestedRow newRow = SuggestedRow(widgetsList: row);
        column.add(newRow);
        row = [];
      }

      i++;
    });

    return column;
  }
```

and one of the widget classes looks like this

```
  class Poster extends StatefulWidget {
  final String posterLocation;

  Poster({required this.posterLocation});

  @override
  _PosterWidgetState createState() => _PosterWidgetState();
}

class _PosterWidgetState extends State<Poster> {
  String? posterLocation;

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    posterLocation = widget.posterLocation;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: InkWell(
      onTap: () async {},
      child: Container(
        width: 80,
        height: 250,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Color(0xFF292B37).withOpacity(0.5),
              spreadRadius: 2,
              blurRadius: 4,
            ),
          ],
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(
              posterLocation.toString(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

The Poster class' (as well as the row and column) initState just doesn't work for some reason so I can't pass the value. It is also worth mentioning that the list is not null, the classes inside of them just don't have any values whatsoever.

I would love to hear what I'm doing wrong and accept your suggestions. Cheers!

EDIT: row class for more context

```
class _SuggestedRowState extends State<SuggestedRow>{

  List<Widget> widgetsList = [];

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    print('---------------------------------------');
    this.widgetsList = widget.widgetsList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: widgetsList,
    );
  }
```

Comment: For once, if `posterLocation` is `String`, why `posterLocation.toString()`? And then I guess you have to print the values on calling and receiving side to find the cause. A reason could be a Future that is not awaited, such that the value comes in too late

Comment: For the posterLocation string, I still don't get how the "String?" works so that's just there to make it work. I already tried printing values, I even got the Poster class to print the posterLocation string but it just can't run initState for some reason. This also applies to the column and row widgets. I'm gonna add the other class in my original post for context

Comment: Have you tried ˋ image: NetworkImage(widget.posterLocation)ˋ? Typically you do not copy the widget parameter but use it directly with widget.parameter

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I haven't thought of that initially and it actually worked. I was actually theorizing on using a stateless widget instead but this'll do. Now I ran into another problem which I hope I can fix. (But if u want to help out, I can't seem to make the column have two row widgets, so it prints 1 poster then new row. Imma try to fix this on my own though) Thanks Man!